# How to keep initial log file in rotating log handler

Tags: java, java.util.logging

I am using Java logging to log the memory static in my file and use `java.util.logging.FileHandler` to implement rotating log. Now I have a situation where my manager wants to keep the initial logging file and rotate the rest of the file. Is there any way I can keep the initial log file but yet rotate the rest of the file.

```
public class TopProcessor extends Handler {
    Handler handler;

    public TopProcessor() throws IOException{
        File dir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "logs");
        dir.mkdirs();
        File fileDir = new File(dir,"metrics");
        fileDir.mkdirs();
        String pattern = "metrics-log-%g.json";
        int count = 5;
        int limit = 500000;
        handler = new TopProcessorHandler(fileDir.getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+pattern, limit, count);
    }

    class TopProcessorHandler extends FileHandler{

        public TopProcessorHandler(String pattern, int limit, int count)
                throws IOException {
            super(pattern, limit, count);           
        }
    }

    private void writeInformationToFile(String information) {
        handler.publish(new LogRecord(Level.ALL, information));
    }


    @Override
    public void close() {
        handler.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void flush() {
        handler.flush();

    }

    @Override
    public void publish(LogRecord record) {
        handler.publish(record);
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Create 2 files one initial log file and other rotating log file..You can merge two files when you want to read logs

Comment: but then loggers will be logging the same information to both log files and duplicating data - waste of space and processing.

Comment: No the first file will just be used for intial logging and the other file for rotating logging